# Read audio output from a TV to a Pi

Tags: audio

Is there a way to have the Raspberry Pi sync LED lights to audio from a TV?
I know how to do it if the audio is played on the Pi but I'm not sure how to get audio from the TV.

Comment: Would acoustic input through a microphone work for you?  Assume that the Pi is "listening" to the ambient sounds just like your own ears do.  Otherwise we'll have to look at a mechanism for capturing the audio signal decoded by your TV/VCR/DVR/CableBox etc.

Comment: How bad would the noise be? If there's no simple/quick solution from decoding TV audio output then a microphone would be ok. How would I connect the microphone to the raspberry pi?

Comment: If you google "raspberry pi microphone" you'll find a bunch of solutions for attaching a mic.  There are USB attachments, raw microphones and even cheap webcams now have microphone input associated with them.

Answer (score 1):

If your TV has a headphone jack you could connect it to the Pi via a USB audio adapter. You will need to setup lightshowpi to audio-in mode.

Answer (score 0):

As you already have the LED flashing working to audio, I will suggest two different ways to get input signal. The first is creative but a little more tricky, the second is more standard and simpler.

1: More complex, but may be more fun ! Skip to 2 below if you want the simple easy sound card option ...
Here is the approach ... Use a transistor or opamp to saturate the audio signal and pipe that signal into the I2S data input line on the GPIO pin. Then setup a simple audio card in for ALSA in a new Linux device tree overlay. Start up the card and capture the input from the card and pipe that signal to your LED setup. Here is the theory on how it works :
* The analog audio signal is saturated to fluctuate violently between 0 and 3.3V. When the simple audio card is set to record, it will generate LR and bit clock signals on the relevant GPIO pins, which you will ignore. The ARM I2S block will read your saturated audio signal in as 1s and 0s constructing ficticious waveform data ... this waveform data should have some pseudo random nature depending on the input signal ... this pseudo fluctuation should resemble the original audio signal in some way in the digital domain. You may find that you need to be a bit more subtle then "saturating" - using a potentiometer on an opamp gain control perhaps ...

2: You can do it using a sound card. USB or Raspberry Pi add on.
For example, the Audio Injector allows the audio straight through (bypass if required) so that there is no delay on the original audio signal.
At the same time, you can read the audio in and do your LED flash thing with it.

Apart from the audio injector sound card, there is another available :
The Cirrus audio card : https://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-accessories/cirrus_logic_audio_card

Link to the Audio Injector Sound card for the Raspberry Pi : http://www.audioinjector.net/#!/rpi-hat
Provides high quality input and output audio.

Hope that helps
Matt